# Clerk auth with next js 13 - how to allow Terms/Privacy page to render without auth?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, clerk

How can I allow a nextjs 13 app to allow the t&cs page to render without a user authenticating?

My file structure is app/(landing)/page - for the main landing page. In the footer of that page, I have links to a t&cs page, which is in the same (landing) folder, saved as terms.tsx.

When I follow the link to terms, the clerk auth sign in screen pops up. I want to render this page without auth.

How can I disable the rendering of the Clerk app when things in the (landing) folder are rendered?

Answer (score 0):

In you `middleware.ts` file you can specify this where you are exporting authMiddleware by doing :

```
import { authMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs";

export default authMiddleware({
  // "/" will be accessible to all users
  publicRoutes: ["/"]
});
```

Use the req object to match against urls. The following example makes all routes but /dashboard public.

```
publicRoutes: req => !req.url.includes('/dashboard')
```

Refer docs for more info : https://clerk.com/docs/references/nextjs/auth-middleware#make-routes-public-by-using-public-routes